# Does accessing your own website result in charges by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an html page hosted using amplify. Does AWS charge everytime the website url is accessed? Does it apply in every case without exception?

I was unable to see the number of clicks for which I was charged. Is there a way to get the click statistics?

I tried to insert google analytics tag in my html, but it gives me access denied errors. Seems, google analytics tag is not compatible with Amplify.

Comment: How is your AWS Amplify app hosted? Is it running on your own web server or are you using Amplify Hosting?

Comment: I am using Amplify hosting. I simply drag and drop the html zip file and deploy.

Comment: Pricing for Amplify Hosting is available at: [AWS Amplify Pricing | Front-End Web & Mobile | Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/pricing/)